# my batch file wont work i keep getting variable was unexpected

Tags: batch-file

```
cls
title The Dead May Follow
echo.
echo hello 
echo.
echo what is your name.
echo.
set /p name=
echo.
echo hello %name% im Nathan.
echo.
echo i wake up in bed after finding out the night before your mother has died.
echo.
echo do i get dressed and go downstairs or do i sleep in longer.
echo.
set /p i=
echo.
if %i% equ get dressed and go downstairs goto get dressed and go downstairs 
if %i% equ sleep longer goto sleep longer
if %i% neq sleep longer goto start
if %i% neq get dressed and go downstairs goto start
:get dressed and go downstairs
cls
echo.
echo your the only one home 
echo.
pause
:sleep longer
cls
echo.
echo you wake up its 11 o clock and nobody is home
pause
exit
```

Comment: it's working fine for me, perhaps you could tell us more what you were doing and how did you get this error

Comment: You would need to tell us what entires you are providing to show the error, and what the error is. What stands out is yout use of `if %i% ...` which will become `if ...` if you provide no input. change that to `if /i "%i%" equ "whatever" ...` - the `/i` introduces case-insensitivity, the quotes ensure that an empty string or one containing spaces behaves itself. Note that "sleep longer" for instance is an invalid label as it contains a space, and batch insists on just one string on each side of the operator. `"sleep longer"` is one string. `sleep longer` is two.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in those lines

```
if %i% equ get dressed and go downstairs goto get dressed and go downstairs
```

gets parsed to a condition `if %i% equ get`, a command to execute if this condition is true: `dressed` and some parameters `go downstairs goto get dressed and go downstairs`

If you have to use spaces in your strings, use

```
if "%i%" equ "get dressed and go downstairs" goto get dressed and go downstairs
```

ok, solved this. Next problem: `goto` needs a one-word-label (no spaces). This code would goto `get` and ignores the rest of the line (Sidenote: a label takes only the first eleven chars; the rest is ignored)

So the above line should read:

```
if "%i%" equ "get dressed and go downstairs" goto getDressed
```

You can use `if /i` to make your condition case insensitive ("Get DresSed" = "get dressed")

Answer (score 0):

Batch file with the changes as suggested by [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo):

```
@echo off
:Restart
cls
title The Dead May Follow
echo.
echo hello 
echo.
echo What is your name?
echo.
set /p "name="
echo.
echo Hello %name% im Nathan.
echo.
echo I wake up in bed after finding out the night before your mother has died.
echo.
echo Do I get dressed and go downstairs or do I sleep in longer?
echo.
set /p "i="
echo.
if /i "%i%" equ "get dressed and go downstairs" goto GetDressed
if /i "%i%" equ "sleep longer" goto SleepLonger
goto Restart
:GetDressed
cls
echo.
echo Your the only one home.
echo.
pause
:SleepLonger
cls
echo.
echo You wake up. It's 11 o clock and nobody is at home.
pause
exit
```

And take a look on [Goto](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx) documentation by Microsoft with the important sentence:

> The **goto** command uses only the first **eight** characters of a label.

A space is allowed in a label, but should not be used. It is better to use CamelCase notation for labels with taking into account that only first 8 characters are significant.

Well, this part of the documentation is not right anymore for Windows 2000 and later versions of Windows. It was true for Windows 95/98. But a simple test with the provided example shows that on Windows XP more than 8 characters of the label are significant.